# extract data using regex?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a code to extract a paragragh in a document using regex and I am using python. The data contains a lot of similar words,but i need to extract the paragraph when it hits the first recurring word.

ex: data.txt

```
extract data 
useful data is extracted

extract numbers
useful numbers are extracted

extract variable 
useful variables are extracted
```

The question is, I have to extract only the below:

```
"extract numbers
useful numbers are extracted"
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly show us the sample input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` and pattern ("`([a-zA-Z].* *\n.[a-zA-Z .,']*)`") for find all paragraphs. Also, it can be used for poems too.
We save your data in `poem` variable:

```
poem = """extract data 
useful data is extracted

extract numbers
useful numbers are extracted

extract variable 
useful variables are extracted"""
```

Now, we find all paragraphs and store them in `par` variable:

```
import re
par = re.findall("([a-zA-Z].* *\n.[a-zA-Z .,']*)",poem)
```

Now, `par` have three elements which you can choose them by `par[0]`, `par[1]` and `par[2]`.
`par[0]` is:

```
'extract data \nuseful data is extracted'
```

`par[1]` is:

```
'extract numbers\nuseful numbers are extracted'
```

`par[2]` is:

```
'extract variable \nuseful variables are extracted'
```